# How to display perfect table format data in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

When we are using hive, data is not displayed in perfect table format. Column name and actual data related to column differs in position if the column name is big. How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean _"using Hive"_ > using deprecated `hive` fat CLI in a terminal? using `beeline` thin JDBC client in a terminal? using the crappy Hue web interface? or using a proper JDBC database front-end like DBeaver or DBVisualizer?

Comment: i am using hive in hadoop to work with hdfs.i want to fetch data from this hdfs files to hive tables.

Comment: Again, what Hive client are you using? Hive obviously runs in Hadoop, so you didn't answer the question. Any JDBC client or beeline will show you the column names. The `hive` command itself shouldn't be used for entering queries

Answer (score 0):

Below is my pure assumption from your question:

You have a dataset with Column name and Data **delimited by space** in it. You are trying to create a hive table on top of it. However you have space in your column names that makes your table look strange.

If the above is correct, one solution is:

1. Add this in your DDL

TBLPROPERTIES ( 'skip.header.line.count' = '1')

2. Change the default column names

   // will change column a's name to a1 ALTER TABLE test_change CHANGE a a1 INT;

Comment: I mean to say data is not coming under its related column.In mysql,we have dash type vertical lines to separate the columns.while in hive, columns are not separated by such lines.so data of one column is going in the area of second column.And i want it to be look like as same as in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got your question.

Do something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbname.tablename( col_1 integer, col_2 integer) row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as textfile;
```

Further, load it from HDFS file like...

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/data.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tablename;
```